# Character encoding is wrong when passed via formData and ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, encoding

I'm trying to pass some data to backend using ajax, but I'm having a problem:

A word like **`voçê`** (**`you`** in Portuguese), when the method receive the data, the value is "voÃ§Ãª". I believe is an encoding problem.

So in jsp i have the form, and in js i'm doing like this:

```js
function getFormData() {
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('example', $('#example').val() || '');

    return data;
}
```

Then the ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '${linkTo[ExampleController].exampleMethod}',
    method: 'POST',
    data: getFormData(),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
```

So tbh, I make it work, adding **`encodeURIComponent`** when setting formData, and in java using URLDecoder in the setter... but it feels like a workaround and not the best way to resolve that issue.

Additional info: jsp is ISO-8859-1, but a already tried to put `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>` at the begining.

Comment: Flagrant [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `Ã§Ãª` string is _byte by byte_ interpretation of UTF-8 encoded string `çê` (byte sequence `\xc3\xa7\xc3\xaa`).